# Why can i see the update succesful of a document?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

i want to update the state 'status' of my document but when after that execute i dont see the change, what is the wrong?

```
let batch = firebaseApp.firestore().batch()
schools
  .get()
  .then(snapshot => {

    snapshot.docs.forEach(doc => {
      const student = firebaseApp
        .firestore()
        .collection('students')
        .doc(doc.id)
      batch.update(student, {
        status: 'changed',
      })

      student.get().then(function(doc) {

        console.log("here", doc.data());
      })
    })
  })
```

at the console i see this: `'here' 'suscribed'` should be `'here' 'changed'`

Answer (score 1):

At the first if you do not need to read any documents in your operation set, you can execute multiple write operations as a single batch that contains any combination of set(), update(), or delete() operations. A batch of writes completes atomically and can write to multiple documents.

A the second the last of line code in batch you should use

```
// Commit the batch
batch.commit().then(function () {
    student.get().then(function(doc) {
       console.log("here", doc.data());
  })
});
```

or

```
batch.commit();
```

To apply the desired changes in the database

Answer (score 1):

There are several errors in your code:

1. As mohammad javad ahmadi mentioned in his anwser you don't commit your batch, therefore the `student` documents are **not** updated.
2. You need to wait that the asynchronous batch operation is completed in order to query back the `student` documents in order to check they were updated.

The following should do the trick:

```
  let batch = firebaseApp.firestore().batch();

  const studentRefs = []; // An array of DocumentReferences

  schools
    .get()
    .then((snapshot) => {
      snapshot.docs.forEach((doc) => {
        const student = firebaseApp
          .firestore()
          .collection('students')
          .doc(doc.id);

        studentRefs.push(student);

        batch.update(student, {
          status: 'changed',
        });
      });
      return batch.commit();
    })
    .then(() => {
      // Here we know the batched write is completed
      // and ALL students documents were updated
      // Let's use Promise.all in order to get all the students

      // We use the studentRefs array that we populated in the previous then() block, in order to build an Array of Promises

      return Promise.all(studentRefs.map((ref) => ref.get()));
    })
    .then((snapshots) => {
      // snapshots is an Array of DocumentSnapshots 
      
      snapshots.forEach(snap => {
          console.log(snap.data());
      })
    });
```

Note how we [chain the promises](https://javascript.info/promise-chaining) returned by [`batch.commit()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.WriteBatch#commit) and by [`Promise.all()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all).